# How to ask your superior to allocate some time for you?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I need to get the signature of my manager for a request to be processed.  Is it OK to ask him

> *Can I have few seconds of your time?*

Comment: Why don't you ask him instead "Could you sign me that document" or whatever you'd like to get signed.

Comment: What makes you unsure that "Can I have few seconds of your time?" is appropriate?

Comment: Maybe, you can try this: "Dear my manager, I need your signature before I can process an important request from a treasurable customer of ours"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Can I have a few seconds of your time?" is correct, but very formal.  If your relationship with your manager is very formal, then this is appropriate.

If your relationship with your boss is a bit more relaxed, the above sentence could seem strange.  It might seem like you're asking for something that's unusually serious.  A less formal phrase would be "Do you have a minute?" or "Do you have a second?"  It's implied that you're asking "Do you have a minute to spare?  And if so, would you be willing to spend it listening to my request?"

Comment: "Can I have a few seconds of your time" very formal? It seems rather informal to me.

Comment: Hi, TRomano. Could it be a typo error that Stephen may want to say this instead "...is correct, but very informal."

Comment: No, it's formal. "A few seconds of your time" is more words than the usual "Have you got a minute?" or "can I have a moment?" or "Got a sec?" Those extra words, and the specificity of "seconds," makes it *formal*, not informal.

Comment: "Can I have a few seconds of your time?" is formal, not informal.  I actually can't think of a way that's *more* formal than that.